# How do I get only a certain number of images from a post (minus the featured image)?

Tags: get-posts, images

I have the following code (see below) that lists all attached images from a post. I'm trying to alter this code to only list the first five images, and also to exclude the featured image from the list. Any help is certainly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

```
<div class="entry-content">
<ul>
    <?php 

     $args = array(
       'post_type' => 'attachment',
       'numberposts' => -1,
       'post_status' => null,
       'post_parent' => $post->ID
      );

      $attachments = get_posts( $args );
         if ( $attachments ) {
            foreach ( $attachments as $attachment ) {
               echo '<li>';
               echo wp_get_attachment_image( $attachment->ID, 'thumbnail' );
               echo '</li>';
              }
         }
    ?>
</ul>
</div><!-- .entry-content -->
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try this:

```
 $args = array(
   'post_type'      => 'attachment',
   'posts_per_page' => 5,
   'post_status'    => 'inherit',
   'post_parent'    => $post->ID,
   'exclude'        => get_post_thumbnail_id( $post->ID )
  );
```

Comment: Thank you @birgire! This worked perfectly. Much appreciated.